# How can I access my @map object from another view function in Backbone/Coffee?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I am trying to work with backbone, coffescript and google maps api. I am able to render the map and add the center marker. I am having a problem adding a collection of locations as morker on the map. How do I share the @map object below with other functions in the view or other parts of the application?

In addMarker @map is undefined.

```
render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template())
    primary = @collection.at(@collection.length - 1)
    if primary
      latlng = {}
      @collection.each(@appendLocation)
      latlng['latitude'] = primary.attributes.latitude;
      latlng['longitude'] = primary.attributes.longitude;
      @renderMap(latlng)
   this

  renderMap: (latlng) ->
    view = new Bone.Views.Map()
    $('#map').append(view.render().el)
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latlng['latitude'], latlng['longitude'])
     myOptions =
      zoom: 12
      center: latlng
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     @map = new google.maps.Map(view.render().el, myOptions)
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      map: @map,
      title:"Hello World!"
    })
    @collection.each(@addMarker)

  addMarker: (location)->
    console.log(@map) <-----UNDEFINED
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(location.attributes.latitude, location.attributes.longitude)
    console.log location.attributes.latitude
    location_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      map: @map,
      title:"Hello World!"
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume that your indentation problem is just a copy/paste error and that your code really looks like this:

```
renderMap: (latlng) ->
  view = new Bone.Views.Map()
  $('#map').append(view.render().el)
  latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latlng['latitude'], latlng['longitude'])
  myOptions =
    zoom: 12
    center: latlng
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  @map = new google.maps.Map(view.render().el, myOptions)
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    map: @map,
    title:"Hello World!"
  })
  @collection.each(@addMarker)
```

The [`each` method on a collection](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) is just a thin wrapper for Underscore's `each` and the [fine manual](http://underscorejs.org/#each) has this to say about `each`:

> **each** `_.each(list, iterator, [context])` Alias: `forEach`
>
> Iterates over a **list** of elements, yielding each in turn to an **iterator** function. The **iterator** is bound to the **context** object, if one is passed.

You're not specifying a context when you use `each`:

```
@collection.each(@addMarker)
```

so `@` (AKA `this`) will be `window` (or whatever the global context is in your environment) inside `addMarker`. You want `@` to be your view so either specify the context:

```
@collection.each(@addMarker, @)
```

or define `addMarker` as a [bound function](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow):

```
addMarker: (location) =>
  #...
```

You could also use [`_.bindAll`](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll) in your view's `initialize` method but that's rare with CoffeeScript.